# How to fetch next records who have same app_id column but different mobile number column

Tags: java, mysql, query-optimization

I have 400 million data in MySQL employee table I want to fetch 1 million records every time  for that I have used limit after fetching first 1 million records I want to fetch next 1 million
records .

**Query==>**

```
select mobile_number ,app_id from employee where department_id='comp' and app_id between '150005050000' and 150005058888' order by app_id limit 0, 100000;

 mobile_number      app_id
| 919xxxxxxx54  |    150005050035 |   <-----  first 1 million nth record
| 9199xxxxxxx6  |    150005050035 |   <------ I want fetch next 1 million records from this line
| 919xxxxxxx35  |    150005050035 |
| 9189xxxxxxx1  |    150005050036 |
| 9199xxxxxxx6  |    150005050036 | 
+---------------+-----------------+
```

suppose this is result and I got my first 1 million records I want to fetch next 1 million but problem is that In my table app_id column have duplicate values so how I will get next records the combination of  mobile_number and app_id column will make that row unique so Is there any solution  so I will fetch next 1 million records as shown in above table;

Comment: how to write java jdbc application to fetch the records after the first 1 million record

Answer (score 0):

To Fetch the next 1 million record just change the `0` in your limit to `1000000` regardless if have the same id.

```
select mobile_number ,app_id from employee where department_id='comp' and app_id between '150005050000' and 150005058888' order by app_id limit 1000000, 1000000;
```

This will skip the first 1million and fetch the next 1 million.

To fetch the 3rd 1million just add another 1 million in your limit like

```
select mobile_number ,app_id from employee where department_id='comp' and app_id between '150005050000' and 150005058888' order by app_id limit 2000000, 1000000;
```

and so on.

The first number in the `LIMIT` is the data to be skipped and the second number is the number of data to be returned.

Comment: but when we change limit from 0 to 100000 it will  take time if we rich to limit 1900000                                      select mobile_number ,app_id from employee where department_id='comp' and app_id between '150005050000' and 150005058888' order by app_id limit 1900000, 100000;                             how i can use mobile_number and app_id column combination to fetch next  records is there any operator or any another way so  we can use to get records after that particular mobile _number and app_id  column

Comment: This is just an answer to your question on how to fetch the next million data. In order to lessen the wait time is another problem to solve and it will be natural occurrence since you have a lot of data in your database.

Comment: You can store the last nth mobile and id and use `WHERE` clause

Comment: It will  be helpful if you have an `auto-increment` column so that you can easily use `where id>nth`, but it's not possible because you already have a table with alot of data and adding an `auto-increment` column make take a long time.

Comment: suppose I have used mobile_number and app_id in query ==> select mobile_number ,app_id from employee where department_id='comp' and app_id between '150005050000' and 150005058888'  and mobile_number='919xxxxxxx54 ' order by app_id limit 0, 1000000;      ===> but it will show only that records who have 919xxxxxxx54 mobile_number but  I want to fetch next records after that 919xxxxxxx54 mobile_number   you can see above result table for your reference

Comment: I dont have id (auto-increment column)  I can find unique record with the help combination of mobile_number and app_id columns

Comment: By the way what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You might [read this](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If this is how you want to use the table, i agree with what ErrBon suggested - put an auto-incremented id column on your table.

Comment: If I added auto-increment id  column then it will decrease performance of query